# switch cases based on a size of a array?

Tags: c#

So let's say I have a string array that contains multiple options, however it can be any size based on user input.

Like the user wants to have `Person 1`, `Person 2`, and `Person 3` in the array, but at any time can add `Person 4` and `Person 5` to the array. How would I be able to add extra cases to a switch in order to include the new people the user added? The theory is that the user has a unlimited amount of slots for people to add or remove.

Edit: I join an array to a string and then split it back to save it in the settings (Ex: `Person 1|Person 2|Person 3`)

Edit again: I want to be able to let the user select a person based on their position, so you would enter 1 for person 1. Again, I don't know how to achieve it nor what it would be called even.

Comment: Use a [`List<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx). Consider it to be an extensible array, to which you can add elements (and remove, and insert...)

Comment: Arrays are fixed size, you can't add more elements. Use `List<T>.Count` property if you want to use array length in `switch` block.

Comment: can please provide example switch case condition... because without knowing condtion how you are going to write switch case

Comment: You don't use `switch` for variable length datasets.

Comment: Sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What do you *actually* want to achieve within that switch? Your switch isn´t the solution, it´s the cause of your problem.

Comment: In an object oriented language such as C# the use of a switch statement usually indicates a design problem.  In your case I suggest that you take a step back from your implementation details and look at the underlying problem.  You have an ordered collection of Person that you wish to persist.  As other have stated a list is probably the best way to represent this collection.  So you need to create a List<Person>.  As for the serialisation, rather than creating a customised method using string concatenation, I suggest that you use json -  2 lines of code and it's done.